# How to test Angular 6 with jest and cucumber?

Tags: javascript, angular, cucumber, jestjs

I have been trying to test an Angular 6 application with Jest and cucumber.

I currently using this module with the application https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-preset-angular but would like to use cucumber js https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js with it and use feature files with the tests and have them in steps

Can this be done?
And how would I go about this?

Comment: It may help: https://www.sitepoint.com/bdd-javascript-cucumber-gherkin/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it:

- protractor: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-cucumber-framework ([Medium](https://medium.com/sparkles-blog/angular-protractor-and-cucumber-552bd75ff6c9))
- cypress: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor ([Medium](https://medium.com/@talktokapildev/angular-e2e-with-cypress-and-cucumber-d689e123d469))
- jest: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-cucumber

Protractor is kind of old so I would go with cypress. Jest is an alternative to Jasmine, it is faster ([some comparison](https://blog.bitsrc.io/angular-9-testing-a-comparison-between-jasmine-jest-and-mocha-acc57bcab836)).